# AWS Lambda function can't import paramiko - Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, importerror, paramiko

I try to import paramiko in my AWS Lambda function, written with Python 3.9. I installed paramiko in a folder with `pip install paramiko -t .` and made a .zip file out of it. Then I added this .zip file to a Lambda Layer and connected it with my Lambda function. And in the Lambda function, I imported paramiko.
But now when I test the code the compiler still tells me: *Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'paramiko'*.

This is the lambda function:

```
import io
import boto3
import paramiko

ACCESS_KEY = '...'
PRIVATE_ACCESS_KEY = '...'
AWS_REGION = 'eu-central-1'
INSTANCE = ['...']
EC2_IP = '...'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #start EC2 instance
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=INSTANCE)
    
    print('Started the instance: ' + str(INSTANCE))
```

Of course, the dots are filled with my credentials.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1FKW.png)

Comment: Please include error text in your post rather than a link to an [external image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: You could [use something like this](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/862c04c1b67a934b7ccc80156c11b10b) to create a paramiko layer regardless of your host platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda unzips layers to `/opt`.
The Python path contains `/opt/python`.
You therefore need to sure that your directory structure inside your zip layer should include a top-level `python` directory and the libraries should all be in that `python` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the first problem. But now I'm getting this error: *"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'asn1' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)"*. Any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: @J.Fasterling you are most likely not running on a linux system!? In that case `pip` installs the wrong binary dependencies, you would need to build the zip file e.g. using docker: https://github.com/jetbridge/paramiko-lambda-layer